# Android Studio 1.0.2 laout-land folder now showing

Tags: android-studio

Using Android Studio 1.0.2 (Windows).
How to make a res/layout-land folder?
I try, it seems to work (no error messages), but the folder does not show up in Android Studio.
However, the folder does exist in the file system.

I have some old project (converted from Android Studio 0.9.x): They seem to work better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to change your structure explorer from Android(I think its default) to Project. You will see the layout-land folder under res.

Comment: How do I change the Structure Explorer from Android to Project_

Answer (score -1):

You can change the structure explorer in Android Studio from Android to Packages:

[image]g

Also after restarting the Android Studio application I was able to see the land folder.